# Is Perl ever a better tool than awk for text processing

Tags: awk, perl

This question was inspired by [a discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21665522/1967396) - see in particular the comment thread under [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21681475/1967396).

I figured this was the site where I could get a definitive answer:

> In what situations would you recommend using Perl rather than awk for complex text (file) processing tasks?

I am looking specifically for examples where Perl either

1. Makes something possible that is not possible with awk
2. Makes the implementation of a particular operation more efficient (faster)
3. Results in more readable / easier to maintain scripts

I recognize that this risks being a "opinion / discussion / religion" type of question - but I hope that the three criteria above allow for an objective comparison of the benefits of these two tools. Also recognize that I am coming at this question as a person with considerable experience with 'nix, but zero formal training; I "learn things as I need them", and I am wondering if there is a reason for me to dig in and learn Perl.

**update** based on a couple of comments, I would like to expand the question:

> Are there particular Perl libraries that you use frequently, and that make you reach for Perl over awk for a class of problems?

Comment: There are a huge variety of libraries for Perl. That's not a feature of the language per se. However, it matters in pratice when a choice between several languages has to be made to accomplish a given task.

Comment: My anecdotal $0.02:
According to our prof. in grad school, a failure of `awk` to produce a report led Wall to invent `perl`. `perl` combines the power of `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and `tr`. So, I would conclude `perl` is better than `awk`.

Comment: @Marco - for example, HTML parsing?

Comment: This is a bad Q, please do not answer it! It' completely off-topic! If you don't understand why then READ! http://unix.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Yes, [for instance](http://www.cpan.org/modules/00modlist.long.html#ID15_WorldWideW).

Comment: Quick answer: yes, that's why it was created.

Comment: @slm - I believe my question falls under the categories of *"invite sharing experiences over opinions"* and *"insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references"*, and as such should be an "allowable subjective question" (ref: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask ). Please explain why you think this is not so.

Comment: @Floris - no the site is not meant to deal w/ Q's as broadly as you've painted your Q. I'm familiar w/ that section of the "subjective" natured Q's and this is well out of scope of that 1 particular bullet. If you had a specific example then there would be some wiggle room but as it stands this Q is just not a good fit.

Comment: I think you are asking, *"Is it worth my time to learn `perl` when I already use `awk`?".*  IMO, if you are **not** interested in programming generally but simply need to use system tools to perform administrative tasks such as parsing text, then no.  However, if you do have a need to do general programming and do not already use one of the dynamically typed, interpreted, general purpose OO languages ubiquitous in *nix environments (perl, python, or ruby) then you yes, you should.  But there is no need to learn more than one of those three.

Comment: @Floris - to give you an example, if there were some actual problem you were attempting to solve and you were comparing 2 potential solution paths, then that would be OK. Also you're very close to going off-topic for another reason. This site deals w/ Unix and Linux, not programming languages (at least not directly). So you'd be better suited on SO than UL. But this Q would just as quickly been closed there too.

Comment: @goldilocks - I already use python; my question was specifically around "classes of text processing tasks for which perl is better than awk". I think the short answer is "tasks that need external libraries" (like HTML parsing) - in which case I would reach for Python and bs4.

Comment: @Floris - also Q's that do not provide a "test" for the A's that are provided is usually a good indicator that the Q is bad. For example, what does "better" mean? How would one test if X is "better" than Y?

Comment: @slm - I thought this was the right site since I consider (wrongly perhaps) awk to be the "built in 'nix tool", whilst perl is considered the "text processing tool of choice" according to some (e.g. http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/108/EssentialPerl.html ). I apologize for clogging up the site; I thought it was an interesting question, and posed in a way that invited specific answers. And if anyone could answer it, I would expect that person to frequent this site. Live another day. As for "better" - I gave three specific criteria (although the third was subjective).

Comment: If you already use python I don't see any point in perl (conversely, as a perl user, python doesn't serve a purpose for me).  These two languages occupy *exactly the same* niche and both of them are certainly capable of doing *anything* conceivable text processing wise.

Comment: @Floris - no harm done, and you learned something from the Q so from that perspective it was productive. It also serves the purpose of educating others about do's & don'ts so it was informative, just not in the way you'd intended 8-). Also if you truly want to get an understanding about this, you can chat w/ regulars in our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Comment: This is definitely a great question, meant to elicit specific answers based on common use cases. .e.g

This is a common use case. INPUT => OUTPUT. An awk program would be complex, while perl can do it so easily. 

This is another common use case AWK does it so much better. 

Hence it depends, if you already know awk, yes, perl will make your time at command line better but perl won't be the only tool you should use. See? Objective answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perl (the Pathologically Eclectic Rubbish Lister) is the youngest software and tried to provide features from `sed`, `grep`, and `awk`. Some systems still do not use perl, so you still need to use `awk`.

If you have small short scripts, then `awk` is faster because it do not use much RAM. But this question is rather not important nowadays.

Perl has the advantage of using a huge library, at example bignum:

```
perl -Mbignum=p,-50 -e 'print 7 / 17 * 2 ** 1024'
74022658494330655024147860797195136090151993250565247519682704773906208395466727932632852195642113248713093779803824795490433138400407947242956458140922662778116418363136978425944182630002816083132493908286100432062606400696408888454667905350718062803228883801119937832891791040171399808266545264132627555599.49778888545891662481444755946205525353595725152256
```

Code readability is always an attribute of the writer. You can write well readable code that does not depend of the language you use.

Comment: The amount of RAM used by `awk` will depend on whatg you're doing with it.

Comment: Wow - that example is certainly worth something. I would normally use `bc` for that though - I don't consider this a "text processing" task. `echo 'scale=16; 7 / 17 * 2 ^ 1024' | bc`.

Comment: Nice, but the results are different! Who's wrong then?

Comment: Ok, fixed. The `p,-50` gives the precision and negative values mean a fixed number of digits after the dot.

Comment: In order to get the numbers to match both need to specify sufficient precision. It turns out that the `bc` command as I used it was only accurate to the first 15 digits: `740226584943306` - presumably because that is the number of digits of precision carried forward during the floating point part of the operation. Interesting.

Comment: with decimal points in bc, no matter what scale you set, the last 3-4 digits always seem a bit iffy. so i just pad scale by 5 more than what i need, just in case. e.g. scale=261 instead of scale=256